# How do you replace a specific character in Column A to values in Column B in Excel?

Tags: excel, copy, paste

I'm working in Excel. The code below are 4 of the rows in Column A. In Column B I have a series of integers starting from 0. I would like the values in Column B to replace the "?" in Column A. I searched Google for advanced copy and paste and find and replace techniques in Excel, but the results just told me to use paste special. I tried attempting to reference Column B in the Find and Replace tool, but was unable to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"<class type=""sItemManager::cITEM_PARAM_DATA"">
<s16 name=""data.mNum"" value=""900""/>
<s16 name=""data.mItemNo"" value=""?""/>
<u32 name=""data.mFlag"" value=""1""/>
<u16 name=""data.mChgNum"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay1"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay2"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay3"" value=""0""/>
<s8 name=""data.mMutationPool"" value=""0""/>
<s8 name=""data.mOwnerId"" value=""4""/>
<u32 name=""data.mKey"" value=""0""/>
</class>"
"<class type=""sItemManager::cITEM_PARAM_DATA"">
<s16 name=""data.mNum"" value=""900""/>
<s16 name=""data.mItemNo"" value=""?""/>
<u32 name=""data.mFlag"" value=""1""/>
<u16 name=""data.mChgNum"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay1"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay2"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay3"" value=""0""/>
<s8 name=""data.mMutationPool"" value=""0""/>
<s8 name=""data.mOwnerId"" value=""4""/>
<u32 name=""data.mKey"" value=""0""/>
</class>"
"<class type=""sItemManager::cITEM_PARAM_DATA"">
<s16 name=""data.mNum"" value=""900""/>
<s16 name=""data.mItemNo"" value=""?""/>
<u32 name=""data.mFlag"" value=""1""/>
<u16 name=""data.mChgNum"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay1"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay2"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay3"" value=""0""/>
<s8 name=""data.mMutationPool"" value=""0""/>
<s8 name=""data.mOwnerId"" value=""4""/>
<u32 name=""data.mKey"" value=""0""/>
</class>"
"<class type=""sItemManager::cITEM_PARAM_DATA"">
<s16 name=""data.mNum"" value=""900""/>
<s16 name=""data.mItemNo"" value=""?""/>
<u32 name=""data.mFlag"" value=""1""/>
<u16 name=""data.mChgNum"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay1"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay2"" value=""0""/>
<u16 name=""data.mDay3"" value=""0""/>
<s8 name=""data.mMutationPool"" value=""0""/>
<s8 name=""data.mOwnerId"" value=""4""/>
<u32 name=""data.mKey"" value=""0""/>
</class>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (you can remove some vars that were included for debugging purposes):

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A4")
    Dim cl1 As Range, cl2 As Range
    For Each cl1 In rng
      Set cl2 = cl1.Offset(0, 1)
      Dim ival As Integer
      ival = cl2.Value
      Dim res As String
      res = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cl1.Text, "?", Trim(Str(ival)))
      cl1 = res
    Next cl1
End Sub
```

or this

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A4")
    Dim cl1 As Range, cl2 As Range
    For Each cl1 In rng
      Set cl2 = cl1.Offset(0, 1)
      Dim ival As Integer
      ival = cl2.Value
      cl1.Replace What:="~?", Replacement:=Str(ival)
    Next cl1
End Sub
```